# concat the '$' symbol with a space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have an HTML like this

```
<SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 8.5pt">$10 rakesh kumar 

asdfkhj&nbsp; $19</SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 8.5pt">.</SPAN>
```

and i want a space between the `$` and the number `10` but m not able to produce a correct expression 
currently i m trying this to concat the `$` with a space

```
var newSelected1 = newSelected.concat(/&#36;/gi,"");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace all '$' with '$ ' use:

```
var m="$10 rakesh kumar asdfkhj&nbsp; $19";
console.info(m.replace(/\$/g, '$ '));
```

If you need only the first match use:

```
var m="$10 rakesh kumar asdfkhj&nbsp; $19";
console.info(m.replace(/\$/, '$ '));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you get that string so I can't show full code...
Buse you can use the `replace` function:

```
var x = '$10';
x = x.replace('$', '$ ');
```

Comment: the variable newSelected1 contains the whole String and i don't think that this `$` get identified as by your code as it is a special symbol.

Comment: @Librak. As I wrote I don't know how he's getting this string... It depends on the format...

Comment: i have given that in the HTML itself

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<pre>$ 10</pre>` and give the following modification in your CSS

```
pre
{
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera */
 white-space:-ms-pre-wrap;  /*IE */
 white-space:-webkit-pre-wrap; /* Chrome and Safari */
 word-wrap: break-word;
 font-family:serif;
 margin-left:0.3em;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex:

```
 /(\$)(\d+)/gi
```

Replace with `$1 $2`

## Result:

```
<SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 8.5pt">$ 10 rakesh kumar 

asdfkhj&nbsp; $ 19</SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 8.5pt">.</SPAN>
```